# How can I identify the MSR (microsoft reserved partition) on a disk with an MBR partition style layout?

Tags: windows, partition, msr

If the disk has a gpt partition layout, the partition type guid will be E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table
But there's no room for information like that in an MBR partition table.

I made a MBR disk layout with a windows 10 install and the partition ID (the one byte in the mbr partition table that has the partition type) from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type and it's 0x07 which is what ends up as the partition ID for a normal NTFS partition. So how can I determine if a partition on an MBR partition layout disk is the MSR?

And now that I think about it, the same thing applies to the recovery partition. It also has a GPT guid, but not an MBR one.